# I'm trying to replace the Colomban CRI CRI engines with twin 72v 3000w dc electric motor. Will the plane fly?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, general-aviation, ultralight, homebuilt

This is the 72V 300W DC motor:
[image: 72v 3000w dc motor]

([source](https://m.de.aliexpress.com/item/4000976238582.html?spm=a2g0n.detail.0.0.643746075yyTiq&gps-id=storeRecommendH5&scm=1007.18500.187585.0&scm_id=1007.18500.187585.0&scm-url=1007.18500.187585.0&pvid=a1c0aa01-ea78-4d69-ae14-dfabb4df2064&_t=gps-id%3AstoreRecommendH5%2Cscm-url%3A1007.18500.187585.0%2Cpvid%3Aa1c0aa01-ea78-4d69-ae14-dfabb4df2064%2Ctpp_buckets%3A668%230%23131923%2365_668%230%23131923%2365_668%23888%233325%2320_668%23888%233325%2320_668%232846%238108%231977_668%235811%2327173%2313_668%236421%2330827%23632_668%232717%237561%23307__668%233374%2315176%23389_668%232846%238108%231977_668%235811%2327173%2313_668%236421%2330827%23632_668%232717%237561%23307_668%233164%239976%23172_668%233374%2315176%23389&pdp_ext_f=%257B%2522scene%2522%253A%25228500%2522%257D&browser_id=4bf7c8cf3fd24e3aaff2b0d5819f5a0b&aff_trace_key=b7a99204e29d4123aa5f5dcb7ccbf07a-1626632818866-04021-UneMJZVf&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=egb7gbxqje4cawlw17abae0114a2df0821c84274fb&gclid=))

Comment: Those are only 4 hp. I think you need a bit more juice to fly a Cri-Cri than 8 hp.  The original's engines total 30 hp.  You need two 12 Kw motors.  You need to then figure out where to put the batteries  such that if they catch fire you won't turn into a roman candle.  And once you have the thing all installed with the same all-up weight as the original, you'll find out your endurance is only about 1/3rd of the gas version.  At this stage, electric power is really only practical for motor gliders unless you can live with the very short range.

Comment: @JohnK, this reads like a good answer...

Comment: I think I'll classify the Cri-Cri as a 'wearable airplane'

Comment: Electric motor power ratings aren't quite the same as gasoline engine ratings -- in general, a 2 HP electric motor will do what a 4-5 HP gasoline engine will do -- but you're still underpowered here with two of these and a 2x conversion factor.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon, what if I should use 6000W motor each?

Comment: @BenFabulous That would give you 16 hp electric, roughly equivalent to the original engines on the Cri Cri -- but they'll weigh more and suck down batteries at least twice as fast as the 3 KW motors -- you might wind up with barely enough run time to take off, go around the pattern, shoot a touch and go, and go back around to land.

Answer (score 7):

Those motors are only 4 hp each. I think you need a bit more juice to fly a Cri-Cri than 8 hp. The original's engines totaled 30 hp. Which means you need two 12 Kw motors. You need to then figure out where to put the batteries such that if they catch fire you won't turn into a roman candle.

And once you have the motors and controllers and batteries and the fireproof battery enclosures all installed with the same all-up weight as the original, you'll find out your endurance is only about 1/3rd of the gas version. At this stage, electric power is really only practical for motor gliders unless you can live with the very short range

Comment: [There is an electric Cri-Cri](http://www.rotexelectric.eu/portfolio-item/cri-cri/) but I can't find specs on its (4) counter-rotating electric motors or battery capacity.

Comment: They're probably about 6-7 Kw each you would think  Reading down the article it sounds like it has an endurance of about an hour, about what I would expect.  You can't really go anywhere, but to just go out and frolic in the sky for 20 minutes, that would be fine. One of the more impressive electric developments I've seen lately is the Open PPG SP140 paramotor.  Makes 160lb of thrust and runs for an hour, not too bad for a paramotor, and only 7 grand complete except for the wing.